# Running scripts on multiple hosts concurrently with fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to create a program that creates multiple droplets, sends a script to each droplet, and initiates the execution all of the scripts without waiting for the output. I have tried to run it in the background, using nohup so that it isn't killed off when disconnected from terminal with the following code:

```
for i in len(script_names):
    c = Connection(host = host[i], user = user[i], connect_kwargs = {"password" : password, "key_filename" : key_filename})
    c.run("nohup python3 /root/" + script_names[i] + " &")
```

I have tried other variations of the same idea, including setting "pty=False", redirecting the output to dev/null with "> /dev/null < /dev/null &" yet nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to issue multiple commands to run scripts on different hosts concurrently without waiting for the output with fabric? Or should I use another package?

Comment: [Parallel execution?](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12.1/usage/parallel.html)

Comment: As far as I could tell parallel execution only works if executing the same command on multiple servers, in this case I'm trying to execute a different command on each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric 2.x's groups aren't fully fleshed out yet, so they aren't well suited for this use case.  In fabric 1.x I would accomplish this by using a dictionary for script_names where the keys are the host strings from your `host` list and the values are the names from script_names currently.  Then I'd have each task perform its run commands in parallel as usual, looking up values using `fabric.api.env.host_string` within the task.  The execution layer of fabric 2.x does not yet support this use-case afaik.  This was my attempt at hacking it in, but the author rightly pointed out that this functionality should be handled in an Executor, which I could not come up with a solution for at the time: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/1595